# How to define type of "this" in function with Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, this, google-closure-compiler

My goal with the Closure Compiler for my project is to achieve 100% typedness, but I'm struggling with a simple jQuery pattern that looks like this :

```
$Controls.on('change input', /** function(this:Element) */ function () {
    $(this).removeClass('is-invalid').next('.invalid-feedback').remove();
});
```

With or without the comment `/** function(this:Element) */`, I'm getting the following error:

```
js/quote.js:61: WARNING - could not determine the type of this expression
        $(this).removeClass('is-invalid').next('.invalid-feedback').remove();
          ^^^^
```

I thought I found that answer from [Github Wiki titled 'Types in the Closure Type System'](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System) in the "Function `this` Type" section, but that doesn't seem to be doing what I thought it'd do.

How do I specify the type of `this` for Closure Compiler?

Comment: Looks like you missed the requirement for the `@this` annotation: [Reference](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#this-type)

Comment: Yup! that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @RandyCasburn for his comment

`/** function(this:Element) */` should be changed to `** @this {Element} */` to essentially cast the type of the context of the function to `Element`

I presume `/** function(this:Element) */` should be used rather to define the type of an argument to a function with an element context

Comment: You aren't casting, that wouldn't effect the internals of the function.  You are *declaring* the expected type of `this`